# Slow Vue style binding

Tags: html, css, performance, vue.js, vuejs2

Vue seems very slow in dynamic style binding (in comparison with jQuery):

I have a container with `overflow-x`, also inner-container which is wider than it's parent. And two buttons with `absolute` position.

- First button `style` attribute is rendered by Vue
- Second button `style` attribute is rendered by jQuery

During container scrolling the first button `style` updating is very slow.
jQuery's is much faster.

Is there is a way somehow to increase its rendering speed?

Here's the code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    left_offset : 0,
    $b2 : null
  },
  computed:{
    _left_offset_style(){
        return `left:${this.left_offset}px`;
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$b2 =  $(this.$el).find('.b2');
  },
  methods: {
    scrollMe(e){
        this.left_offset = parseInt($(e.target).scrollLeft());
        this.$b2.css({left:`${this.left_offset}px`} );      
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-container{
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
}

button{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
}

.b2{
  top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="container" @scroll="scrollMe">
    <button :style="_left_offset_style" class="b1">b1</button>
    <button class="b2">b2</button>
    <div class="inner-container"></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there is a way somehow to increase it's rendering speed?

You do not need jquery at all. Just add a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on the `b1` button and use it to change the `left` CSS property based on the [`scrollLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) in the scroll listener

**html**

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="container" @scroll="scrollMe">
    <button ref="b1" class="b1">b1</button>
    <div class="inner-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    scrollMe(e) {
      console.log("scroll left", e.target.scrollLeft);
      this.$refs.b1.style.left = e.target.scrollLeft + "px";
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w47Lz9re/2/)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the effect you're trying to achieve (adding some fixed buttons that hover over a scrollable container) then you don't need Vue or JQuery to achieve that effect at all, you can do it entirely using HTML & CSS.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.btn-1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.btn-2 {
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
}

.scroll-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scrollable-content {
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn-1">b1</button>
  <button class="btn-2">b2</button>
  <div class="scroll-container">
    <div class="scrollable-content"></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, FYI, Vue batches changes and executes DOM updates in cycle, docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick